# Groovy not removing elemnts from array

Tags: groovy

I want to remove strings starting with `#` or `//` from the `lines`  array.
It is not working.

Here is the code (excluding the preliminaries like reading the file etc):

```
       def file =  new File("$_file").text.replaceAll("\\r\\n|\\r|\\n", " ");


          String[] lines_ = file.split("\\s*;\\s*");

          println(lines_);

        for(line in lines_)
        {

          if(line.take(1) =='#' || line.take(2) == '//')
          {

            remove(lines_ , line);
          }             

         }
```

Here is the `remove` function

```
public static String[] remove(String[] input, String deleteMe) 
{
    if (input != null) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(input));
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            if (list.get(i).equals(deleteMe)) {
                list.remove(i);
            }
        }
        return list.toArray(new String[0]);
    } else {
        return new String[0];
    }
}
```

Here is the `$_file`

```
canvas cvs {

  width:100,
  dfdf:60
}
;
//this is a comment;
#also a comment;
sprite  ball{


   body : hr,
   Image: here
}
;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can read the lines from the file with `readLines()`, then just call `findAll` like so:

```
String[] lines = new File("$_file")
    .readLines()
    .findAll { !it.startsWith('#') && !it.startsWith('//') }
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it!

I changed remove function to:

```
static String[] remove(String[] str_array , String what){


    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(str_array));
    list.remove(what);
    str_array = list.toArray(new String[0]);

    return str_array;
}
```

and `remove(lines_,line)` to `lines_ = remove(lines,line)`

And its ok now!